# Java calculator is crashing

Tags: java

I am making this really cool calculator app. Everything works, except for one thing. When the user presses an invalid equation, such as 1+, or 5-, it crashes. What I mean my crash is this: When it says, sorry, calculator has stopped. I tried fixing it, but it didn't work.

Java:

```
if (number1.getText().toString().contains("+")){
    String[] retVal;
    if (number1.getText().length() != 0) {
        //num1 = Float.parseFloat(num1 + "+");
        expr = number1.getText().toString();
        retVal = expr.split("\\+");
        if ((retVal[0].length() >= 2) || retVal[1].length() >= 2)
            return;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(retVal[0]);
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(retVal[1]);
        resultnum = num1+num2;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a valid math expression",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

This is the line in which I added to fix the issue:(However, did not work)

```
if ((retVal[0].length() >= 2) || retVal[1].length() >= 2)
    return;
```

I am a beginner in Java programming. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: When you say "crashes", what do you mean? Do you you get an exception? A stack-trace? Please include these in your question so we can help you fix the problem.

Comment: Also, check first after `retVal = expr.split(...)` to see if you have 2 entries; if it didn't split to 2 (or more) entries, then `retVal[1]` will not be valid. Such as `if (retVal.length < 2) { //do error }`

Comment: There are some troubleshooting instructions in [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) The error log probably said `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and the code line number where it happens. Then you would put a break point there, debug the app and realize that `retVal` only has one element after the split.

Comment: *"Please help me as soon as possible.."* No. I'm spending my effort helping people with better time management skills. If you need urgent help, you're already too late for mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing as you don't include the exact error, but if your input is `1+` then

```
retVal = expr.split("\\+");
```

will return one string (not two), which means that

```
 retVal[1].length()
```

will cause an exception as `retVal[1]` does not exist.

To avoid this error, you should check `retval` after calling `split()` to see if it contains two elements. If it doesn't then tell your user their equation was invalid. For example,

```
 if (retVal.length != 2) {
     // Tell the user ...
 }
```

Comment: So how do I do that? Can you give me the code please?

Comment: Arrays have a `length` property as in `retVal.length`. Use that to check the number of elements after the split.